# UK postcodes for geocodes

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, postal-code

I've looked around for this most of the morning and haven't found a suitable way of finding UK postcodes from their geolocations (longitude / latitude) using Google Maps, is there anyone out there with any experience of this?

I understand Royal Mail has an API for the postcode search from a geolocation, but it's horribly expensive for such data, surely there has to be another way?

To note, the functionality I'm trying to achieve is that of: http://www.rightmove.co.uk/draw-a-search.html. When the shape is created, a list of UK postcodes (the first 3/4 digits of the postcode, for the area) must be given.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding

Comment: I did come across that, but there seems to be nothing there for areas, just long/lats? In theory I'd need a number of geolocations to be passed in and all the postcodes given that are in that area.

Comment: Isn't that a "a suitable way of finding UK postcodes from their geolocations (longitude / latitude)"?

Comment: There's a 3rd paragraph in the question, from the beginning of posting it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have at least 3 requirements

1. A list of UK postcodes with coordinates.
2. Drawing polygon on Map.
3. Locating postcodes within polygon.

Google for #1 (uk postcode coordinates free). Store data required in database

Use Google [**Shape**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes#rectangle_add) library for #2

For # 3 you

Use the following query to eliminate the majority of postcode outside polygon.(Server side)

```
SELECT  name, lat, lng FROM table WHERE (lat BETWEEN minLat 
                      AND minLat )AND (lng BETWEEN minLng AND minLng)
```

to

Then use point in polygon to eliminate points outside polygon (client side)

```
function pointInPolygon(polySides,polyX,polyY,x,y) {
 var j = polySides-1 ;
  oddNodes = 0;
  for (i=0; i<polySides; i++) {
    if (polyY[i]<y && polyY[j]>=y  ||  polyY[j]<y && polyY[i]>=y) {
        if (polyX[i]+(y-polyY[i])/(polyY[j]-polyY[i])*(polyX[j]-polyX[i])<x)  {
            oddNodes=!oddNodes; 
        }
    }
   j=i; }

  return oddNodes;
}
```

This [**Link**](http://daviestrachan.co.uk/polygon/JSONMapPolygon.html) shows #2 & #3

Comment: For part 3, Google Maps has a containsLocation method whcih may be easier to use, https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/poly-containsLocation